# Is there a way to manually launch typescript compilation in VS2015

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a rather large TS solution (hundreds of files), and I suffer from some sort professional deformation where I maniacally CTRL+S my code as I type.

When "compile on save" is enabled in my project properties, it will of course compile typescript, however if I CTRL+S before the compilation is over, it will inevitably crash my VS2015 instance.

This results is lost time since I need to reload my solution, reopen the files I was working on and severely augments my murderous rage.

I can't find a way to manually start TS compilation through the UI or keyboard shortcuts (without rebuilding/building the project - just the .ts files)

Is there a way to easily control when TS will compile, or am I bound to go crazy?

Comment: I am already using "Bundler & Minifier" task runner and I am not looking to complexify my toolchain with something that I don't really need.

Comment: This will probably not be what you want to hear then, but having a separate watcher to compile (not necessarily "build" and definitely not minify) is the best way to go on the long run. You separate all the building tasks from the editor. Visual Studio makes it easy to have a task runner doing that for you. That, or you can go to the folder and run "tsc".